# Laplace diffrential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x +3y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3x +2y$$
Find general solution.

I know there is a solution through eigenvalues. But I want to solve it with Laplace transformation.

I almost get the right answer. I am missing a negative sign.

I get with one-sided Laplace: 
$$x(t)=C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{5t}$$
$$y(t)=C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{5t}$$

Real answer:
$$x(t)=C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{5t}$$

$$y(t)=-C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{5t}$$
Have I forgot something very basic?

Comment: There is a lot of re-labeling of arbitrary constants as you solve with laplace transforms. Whether you call the "final form" of your constant $C_1$ or $-C_1$ does not matter so both general solutions are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Letting capital letters denote the laplace transform and taking the laplace transform of both equations, we get

$$ sX(s)-x(0) = 2X(s) + 3Y(s) $$
$$ sY(s)-y(0) = 3X(s) + 2Y(s) $$

Collecting like terms we get

$$(s-2)X(s)-3Y(s)-x(0)=0$$
$$(s-2)Y(s)-3X(s)-y(0)=0$$

Using elimination, we can get

$$-9Y(s)-3x(0)+(s-2)^2Y(s)-(s-2)y(0)=0$$

Moving things around a bit

$$Y(s) = \frac{(s-2)y(0)+3x(0)}{(s-5)(s+1)}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition,

$$Y(s) = \frac{C_1}{s+1} + \frac{C_2}{s-5} \Rightarrow y(t) = C_1 e^{-t} + C_2 e^{5t}$$

Plugging back into your original second equation,

$$ -C_1 e^{-t} + 5C_2 e^{5t} = 3x(t) + 2(C_1 e^{-t} + C_2 e^{5t}) $$

Solving for $x(t)$, we get

$$x(t) = -C_1 e^{-t} + C_2 e^{5t}$$

which is equivalent to the solution you're looking for.

Since you haven't posted your own work, I can't point to the exact mistake you made, but its likely you just made an algebraic error.

Also, contrary to what other commenters have said, the choice of $-C_1$ versus $+C_1$ *does* matter since this is a system. It is critical that the $e^{-t}$ term in the solution for $x(t)$ has the opposite sign of $y(t)$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I didn't think it through at all.